Can ago be used with since?
Is this sentence correct:

He has prepared for the Basic Competence Test since three years ago.


No, they fight each other the way you have it. He has prepared for the Basic Competence Test starting three years ago. OR He has prepared for the Basic Competence Test since arriving
three years ago. OR He prepared for the Basic Competence Test three years ago. OR He has prepared for the Basic Competence Test since finishing school.

~play ˈCupid
to try to start a romantic relationship between two people
Sandy has played Cupid to dozens of couples since she set up a dating agency six years ago. [Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, 8th edition] Does that mean if I put a past tense clause after since, then I can put ago as well? Thank you so much for your time.

as of three years ago

You could also use the present perfect progressive:  He has been preparing for the exam for the last three years.

I'd suggest editing that dictionary example into your question and making it clear that you're asking about how you could alter it. It doesn't even have to be a past tense clause, btw, you could say "since setting up a dating agency six years ago."

@Andy Bonner. Thank you for your time, but this sentence has been debated by many English teachers. It was about  grammatical usage I referred to.

The sentence "He has prepared for the Basic Competence Test since three years ago" is not grammatically correct.
"Since" is used to refer to a point in time when something started and continues up to the present. It needs to be followed by a specific time reference (e.g., a date, a specific event, etc.).
"Ago" is used to refer to a point in time relative to now, often with a number (e.g., "three years ago").
Using "since" and "ago" together is typically not correct because "since" already implies a starting point in the past, and "ago" implies a past time as well, but they serve different grammatical functions.
The sentence would be correct if rephrased as:
"He has prepared for the Basic Competence Test for three years." (Using "for" to indicate duration)
As for your example from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary ("Sandy has played Cupid to dozens of couples since she set up a dating agency six years ago"), it works because "since" refers to a specific point in time when Sandy set up the agency, and "six years ago" specifies when that happened. In this case, "since" and "ago" aren't used directly together but rather in two different clauses—"since" introduces the starting point, and "six years ago" gives context for when that starting point occurred.
So, the structure is:
"Sandy has played Cupid (action) since [specific time/event] (she set up a dating agency), which happened six years ago."
This kind of construction works, but you can't directly follow "since" with "ago" in one phrase.
The following grammatically correct sentences follow this structure:
He's been living in the city since he moved there five years ago.
I've been playing piano since I took my first lesson three years ago.
